# Problems sending UDP with CCL

Tags: sockets, udp, common-lisp, ccl

when I try to send a message as follow:

```
(let* ((temp-buffer message)
 (out-vector (make-array (length temp-buffer) 
             :element-type'(unsigned-byte 8)
             :initial-contents temp-buffer))
 (s (ccl:make-socket :remote-host host :remote-port port :type :datagram )))
(ccl:send-to s out-vector (length out-vector))
(ccl::close s))
```

I get the following error:

```
on #<CCL::UDP-SOCKET #x302000D9FCFD> : 
Socket is already connected (error #56) during sendto
```

Initially, this code was effective. 
Could anyone explain this error message and how to solve it.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: You could try to post the question on the CCL developer list: [https://lists.clozure.com/mailman/listinfo/openmcl-devel](https://lists.clozure.com/mailman/listinfo/openmcl-devel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work.

```
(let* ((temp-buffer message)
       (out-vector (make-array (length temp-buffer)
                               :element-type'(unsigned-byte 8)
                               :initial-contents temp-buffer))
       (s (ccl:make-socket :type :datagram)))
  (ccl:send-to s out-vector (length out-vector) :remote-host host :remote-port port)
  (ccl::close s))
```